# check if log-in into hotspot

Tags: android, sdk, resolve

I'm trying to write an android software which will connect to my university hotspot automatically.

For now, I'm trying to know if I'm in a local hotspot or actually on the internet.
My way to do is trying to resolve a website like "http://google.com".
If the returned IP is local, I know I'm on a hotspot (but maybe not the good one) thanks to the local DNS. If the ip is an external one, I will assume it's google's one.

However, I don't know if it's because of my university Firewall or not, but when I'm trying to resolve any host, it says : "Unable to resolve host "http://google.com": No address associated with hostname".

Here is my code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wi = wm.getConnectionInfo();


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            String hostName = "http://google.com";
            InetAddress hostInetAddress;
            try {
                hostInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();




    wm.getDhcpInfo();
    String toto = wm.getDhcpInfo().toString();
}
```

Here is my manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
    // otherwise check if we are connected
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working, when I'm connected to the network but not logged-in, it return true.

Comment: it does exactly what the method says - returns a boolean if connected. What's not to work?

Comment: I want to check if I'm logged-in the network. We have to type our ID/password on a webpage in order to have the full access to internet. In other words, if I want to go to stackoverflow.com and I'm not connected, I will be redirected to the loggon webpage. In Windows or Android, I have a notification that tell me I have to log-on. I want to check if I'm logged-in or not